# How can I contain more than 2 models in one template?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, model

I'm student who studying Django myself.
I will brief my project simply.

1. Get baseball players' record
2. Display it in my website

My project complete is within hailing distance. But I have a problem.
This is my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from displayer.models import Profile, SeasonRecord

def index(request):
    profile_list = Profile.objects.all().order_by('-no')[:5]
    context = {'profile_list': profile_list}

    return render(request, 'displayer/index.html', context)

def data(request, profile_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=profile_id)
    season = SeasonRecord.objects.all().order_by('-no')[:5]
    context = {'profile': profile, 'season':season}

    return render(request, 'displayer/data.html', context)
```

I want to contain 2 models (Profile, SeasonRecord) in view function(data) and I am going to contain more models in this view function. But It contains only Profile model.

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.contrib import admin
from displayer import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^displayer/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^displayer/(?P<profile_id>\d+)/$', views.data, name='data'),
]
```

This is data.html

```html
<h1>{{ profile.number }}</h1>
<h1>{{ profile.name }}</h1>

<table align="left" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>position</td>
    <td>debut</td>
    <td>born</td>
    <td>body</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ profile.position }}</td>
    <td>{{ profile.debut }}</td>
    <td>{{ profile.born }}</td>
    <td>{{ profile.body }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<table align="left" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>avg</td>
        <td>rbi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ season.avg }}</td>
        <td>{{ season.rbi }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Help me.. What should I do?

I'm using django version 1.10.5, python version 3.5.2

Comment: season returns more than one object so you need to loop over it in template. Profile returns one object therefore you don't need to loop over it. I think that's where you have made your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the django template loop

```
<table align="left" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>avg</td>
        <td>rbi</td>
    </tr>
    {% for season in seasons %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ season.avg }}</td>
        <td>{{ season.rbi }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

and this needs to be

```
context = {'profile': profile, 'season':seasons}
```

Of course these can be any variable names you want. I am pluralizing season in keeping with the custom

Comment: I completed project by your help. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help.